# Why does this error 'TypeError: undefined is not an object' occur

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I am trying to load up a star.js with an svg-image.
I am using Ubuntu version 21.04.
And i have used the command expo install react-native-svg.

Below here is my file.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Card } from "react-native-paper";
import { SvgXml } from "react-native-svg";
import { star } from "../../../../assets/star";

const Title = styled.Text`
  font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.fonts.body};
  font-size ${(props) => props.theme.fontSizes.body};
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.ui.primary};
`;

const Info = styled.View`
  padding: ${(props) => props.theme.space[3]};
`;

const Address = styled(Text)`
font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.fonts.body};
font-size ${(props) => props.theme.fontSizes.caption};
`;

const ResturantCard = styled(Card)`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.ui.tertiary};
`;

const ResturantCardCover = styled(Card.Cover)`
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.ui.tertiary};
`;

export const ResturantInfo = ({ resturant = {} }) => {
  const {
    name = "Some Resturant",
    icon,
    photos = [
      "https://eatforum.org/content/uploads/2018/05/table_with_food_top_view_900x700.jpg",
    ],
    address = "100 some random street",
    openingHours = true,
    rating = 4,
    isClosedTemporarily,
  } = resturant;

  return (
    <ResturantCard elevation={5}>
      <ResturantCardCover key={name} source={{ uri: photos[0] }} />
      <Info>
        <Title>{name}</Title>
        <SvgXml xml={star}/>
        <Address>{address}</Address>
      </Info>
    </ResturantCard>
  );
};
```

Below down here is my svg file:
I would to use this star.s file to use a star image to submit a
rating to a resturang.

```
export default `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 511.999 511.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.999 511.999;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#FFDC64;" d="M452.71,157.937l-133.741-12.404L265.843,22.17c-3.72-8.638-15.967-8.638-19.686,0l-53.126,123.362
    L59.29,157.937c-9.365,0.868-13.149,12.516-6.084,18.723l100.908,88.646l-29.531,131.029c-2.068,9.175,7.841,16.373,15.927,11.572
    L256,339.331l115.49,68.576c8.087,4.802,17.994-2.397,15.927-11.572l-29.532-131.029l100.909-88.646
    C465.859,170.453,462.074,158.805,452.71,157.937z"/>
<g>
    <path style="fill:#FFF082;" d="M119.278,17.923c6.818,9.47,26.062,50.14,37.064,73.842c1.73,3.726-2.945,7.092-5.93,4.269
        C131.425,78.082,98.96,46.93,92.142,37.459c-5.395-7.493-3.694-17.941,3.8-23.336C103.435,8.728,113.883,10.43,119.278,17.923z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FFF082;" d="M392.722,17.923c-6.818,9.47-26.062,50.14-37.064,73.842c-1.73,3.726,2.945,7.092,5.93,4.269
        c18.987-17.952,51.451-49.105,58.27-58.575c5.395-7.493,3.694-17.941-3.8-23.336C408.565,8.728,398.117,10.43,392.722,17.923z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FFF082;" d="M500.461,295.629c-11.094-3.618-55.689-9.595-81.612-12.875c-4.075-0.516-5.861,4.961-2.266,6.947
        c22.873,12.635,62.416,34.099,73.51,37.717c8.778,2.863,18.215-1.932,21.078-10.711
        C514.034,307.928,509.239,298.492,500.461,295.629z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FFF082;" d="M11.539,295.629c11.094-3.618,55.689-9.595,81.612-12.875c4.075-0.516,5.861,4.961,2.266,6.947
        c-22.873,12.635-62.416,34.099-73.51,37.717c-8.778,2.863-18.215-1.932-21.078-10.711S2.761,298.492,11.539,295.629z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FFF082;" d="M239.794,484.31c0-11.669,8.145-55.919,13.065-81.582c0.773-4.034,6.534-4.034,7.307,0
        c4.92,25.663,13.065,69.913,13.065,81.582c0,9.233-7.485,16.718-16.718,16.718C247.279,501.029,239.794,493.543,239.794,484.31z"/>
</g>
<path style="fill:#FFC850;" d="M285.161,67.03l-19.319-44.86c-3.72-8.638-15.967-8.638-19.686,0L193.03,145.532L59.29,157.937
    c-9.365,0.868-13.149,12.516-6.084,18.723l100.908,88.646l-29.531,131.029c-2.068,9.175,7.841,16.373,15.927,11.572l15.371-9.127
    C181.08,235.66,251.922,115.918,285.161,67.03z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>`;
```

But i get an error below with these pictures:

And these are the errors below:

[image: Error-message]

[image: Error-message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that i wrote it wrong:

import { star } from "../../../../assets/star";

After i changed it to

import star from "../../../../assets/star";'

It worked!